# CreateProcess() and ShellExecute() freeze when waiting for svchost.exe

Tags: winapi, windows-8, createprocess, shellexecute, c++builder-xe5

Under Windows 8 I'm starting an external program but it get stuck as a background process waiting for svchost.exe to return. If I start the same application manually (double click) it starts just fine.
If I run the same code under Windows 7, it works just fine.

I have mainly tried 3 ways of executing the application:

```
ShellExecute(NULL,L"open","MyApp.exe",NULL,NULL,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

This returns ok but the application freeze waiting for svchost.exe.
Then I tried the Extended version.

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShExecInfo;

ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
ShExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
ShExecInfo.hwnd = Application->MainFormHandle;
ShExecInfo.lpVerb = L"open";
ShExecInfo.lpFile = L"MyApp.exe"
ShExecInfo.lpParameters = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = L"MyWorkDir";
ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
ShExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL;

res = ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo);
```

This also returns ok and I hInstApp is set, but still freeze as before.
Then I tried CreateProcess().

```
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

res = CreateProcess(L"MyApp.exe",NULL,NULL,NULL,false,0,NULL,L"MyWorkDir",&si,&pi);
```

This also returns ok and the PROCESS_INFORMATION is filled in correctly, but still it freeze.
RAD Studio shows a debug message when I create the process:

```
Application "\??\C:\Windows\Program Files (x86)\ ... MyApp.exe" found in cache
Application "\??\C:\Windows\Program Files (x86)\ ... MyApp.exe" cache bypassed reason 0x86
```

In Windows 8 Task manager I can see that the Process is waiting on svchost.exe to return.

Comment: Where in task manager shows you that it's waiting on svchost.exe ?

Comment: In the "Information" tab, right click on the main process and select "Analyze". It will show what process it is waiting for.

Comment: Sounds like you're running the parent process in a debugger?  What happens if you don't?

Comment: @HarryJohnston The above problem description applies to both stand alone and debugger, no difference. Let me remind you that this works perfectly well under Windows 7 and Vista.

Comment: Any chance UAC elevation is involved?  Can you break into the child process with a debugger, to see what state it's in?  Is this happening with *any* child process, or just this specific one?

Comment: @HarryJohnston No it's an external application from a third party. svchost.exe is assigned by Windows to host services used by the application. I'm not quite sure, but I think it is hosting an RPC call in this case. If i kill the svchost.exe process, the application starts but, of course, crash the whole windows a few seconds later. I have tried to run my host app as administrator but no difference. Maybe it has to do something with inherited handlers?

Comment: There really isn't all that much that child processes inherit.  You're passing through the same environment variables that you were given, so that's OK.  You should double-check that the current directory is the same in both cases.  The only other thing I can think of is that the app might be unusually sensitive to the command line, e.g., it must (or perhaps must not!) contain the full path to the executable, I don't recall offhand what Explorer does when you double-click.  (Or there might be some new Windows 8 weirdness going on that I'm not familiar with yet.)

Comment: Process Explorer might be useful; you could compare the process details when you launch the third-party process directly with those when you launch it from your host application.  If nothing else, it would be an easy way to double-check that the command line and current directory are identical.